# Copy PuTTY session colors and font from one to another

Tags: putty

I have around 30 saved PuTTY sessions and in one of the PuTTY Session I have customized some colors and it looks better than others. Now I want this color and font settings to the rest of the other 29 saved PuTTY sessions. Is there any easy way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only by editing your Windows Registry.

The sessions are stored in `[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\SimonTatham\PuTTY\Sessions]`

- Export your colored stored session to a `.reg` file.
- Filter the `.reg` file only to the `Colour*` and `*Font*` entries.
- Clone whole `.reg` file contents (except for a header) for each session you want to modify.
- Edit section names to names of the sessions you want to modify.
- Import back.

Your `.reg` file will look like:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\SimonTatham\PuTTY\Sessions\Session you want to modify 1]
"Colour0"="187,187,187"
"Colour1"="255,255,255"
"Colour2"="0,0,0"
...

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\SimonTatham\PuTTY\Sessions\Session you want to modify 2]
"Colour0"="187,187,187"
"Colour1"="255,255,255"
"Colour2"="0,0,0"
...

...
```

Comment: Beat me to it, well played. I was looking for similar for KiTTy (I don't use PuTTy) and they're all stored in Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\9bis.com\KiTTY\Sessions\